# UFT not able to click on WebButton in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, qtp, hp-uft

I am seeing a strange issue while using Object Spy and my web application. All of the objects are being highlighted in the wrong location relative to the correct location.

---

[image: WebButton]

---

i.e. a WebButton has the x,y coordinate 920, 460 but when I try to spy it, I need to keep my cursor on let’s say 860, 420. Then its shows the property of that object. If I hover my mouse/cursor on that button, it shows some other object's property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to determine that the zoom in IE had been adjusted to 105% instead of 100%. Ensure that zoom is set to 100% before attempting to troubleshoot further.

[Resource](http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/148990-strange-issue-qtp-object-spy.html)

Comment: Yeah, that might do it...  I wonder, then:  you said "a WebButton has the x,y coordinate 920, 460 but when I try to spy it, I need to keep my cursor on let’s say 860, 420. ".  If GUISPY told you 920,460 as fact, then perhaps your cursor really was over 920,460 instead of 860,420...   but you were SEEING the image of the button down at at 980, 500?

Comment: Agreed...at any rate, UFT does not take into account zoom when spying or clicking buttons.

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself. Resetting to 100% fixed it